# Write instance to Mongo with information about class

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, spring-data

How can I store information about class of object when I save it to Mongo? I'm using Scala and Play. 
More details. Lets say, we have Trait User and 2 implementations: Admin and Member. And then we try to save them to one Mongo collection.

```
    class UserDao {

      private def collection = ReactiveMongoPlugin.db.collection[JSONCollection]("users")

      def save(user:User):Future[User] = {
        collection.save(user) //Fail
      }
    }
```

And we get error. Because we need Reads and Writes for Trait which are really ugly and complicated things..

Before I've written application in Java and Spring Mongo and there wasn't any problems. Spring automagically add _class field to this bson object, which is stored in Mongo. And after read from this collection spring knows which should create. And in Play there is nothing like that.

Please, help me..

Answer (score 0):

I found information, that this is impossible in play reactive mongo driver and generally in play mongo. So there is only one way- write your own driver or think about different solution.